# Wand Damage Increased by Which Attributes and Skills?

Tags: torchlight

In Torchlight, is wand damage increased by raising Magic (because they have elemental magic damage) or by Dexterity (because they are ranged weapons) or both?

Related question...  If you are dual wielding wands, does the Dual Wielding skill increase the damage that wands do?

Comment: The latter is "yes" for sure. Can't remember 'bout the 1st one.

Answer (score 4):

Try it for yourself! When you've leveled up, just up your skills and watch the damage you do.

You'll see that for wands, the 'actual damage' is benefited from the dexterity stat and the magic damage is benefited from the magic stat.  Since higher level wands are mostly magic damage, you'll want to focus on that if you're serious about high wand damage.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is this:

Dex increases damage for all ranged weapons
Magic increases all elemental damage for all weapons

So then it seems wands benefit from both.  However, I think that wands benefit more from Magic.

Answer (score 0):

When you're leveling up, you can put a few points into a skill, look at the effect, and then remove those points if you don't like the effect.  This "undo" option appears to last as long as you keep the skill point window open.

So you can easily try it out to see which skill has the best effect on your wand damage.